# response.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript

How can I fix the TypeError?

```
const settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://yahoo-weather5.p.rapidapi.com/weather?location=izmir&format=json&u=f",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "yahoo-weather5.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    };    
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        var str = '';
        response.forEach(item => {
            str += ' <tr>';
            str += '     <td>' + item.day + '</td>';
            str += '     <td>' + item.date + '</td>';
            str += '     <td>' + item.sunset + '</td>';
            str += '     <td>' + item.Case_Fatality_Rate + '</td>';
            str += ' </tr>';
        });
        jQuery("#gridData").html(str);
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: `response` is likely not an array or even an array-like object. Please also replace the screenshots of code with text [mcve]s instead.

Comment: when ı use array,, ı cant see on dashboard. just ı see console. what can ı do

Comment: @exe why don't you `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: if you put `console.log(response);` before that line that throws the error, you'll see what you get

Comment: `JSON.parse(response).forEach()`

Comment: I really think rhe response is an Object `{}` not an Array `[]`

Comment: The ajax done function is called whether or not the request is successful, is the request actually succeeding and returning a valid response?

Comment: Please do not share your API key publicly

Comment: PS: `"async": true,` is not needed. It's async by default.

Answer (score 0):

That Specific API call returns with the 'data' object according to the [API docs](https://rapidapi.com/apishub/api/yahoo-weather5). You can try looping over the data attribute, but I'm also pretty sure it returns an object:

```
response.data
```

I can't really be more helpful since you have to pay to see the results of the api call. Also as other comments said, when in doubt, console.log().

Answer (score 0):

Add in settings `dataType: "json"` so the response will be formatted accordingly if you expect a json array:

```
const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://yahoo-weather5.p.rapidapi.com/weather?location=izmir&format=json&u=f",
    "method": "GET",
    "dataType": "json", // add this
    ...
};
```

Comment: jQuey DOCS: *dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))*

Comment: It's not that intelligent when the server responds with a valid json format and lacks the `application/json` content-type.